# Determining the loading time of an external page

Tags: php, http

How can I determine the loading time of an external page using PHP?
For example, finding the loading time of https://stackoverflow.com/questions.

Comment: Are you looking to find how long it takes for PHP to run, or how long the HTML takes to load and render in the browser?

Comment: Subract the starttime from the endtime and use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 4):

If it is on another server, then it is basically the same way you would time something else, only instead of calling a locally defined function, you use file_get_contents:

```
$t = microtime( TRUE );
file_get_contents( "your tested url" );
$t = microtime( TRUE ) - $t;
print "It took $t seconds!";
```

As a warning, that will also include the time it takes to make the request and receive the request (time spent over the wire). Unfortunately, unless you actually have access to that server, that cannot be helped.

Now, if you're trying to get the render time of your site, you can use `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean`:

```
$t = microtime( TRUE );
ob_start();
// do all of your rendering
ob_end_clean();
$t = microtime( TRUE ) - $t;
print "It took $t seconds!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Measuring page load times must be done on the client. Implementing a full browser using PHP is not a trivial task.

- Do you want to measure the page load times of some remote website?
- Or do you want to instrument your own site to measure page load times?
- Do you really mean page load times or do you mean the time taken to process each request?
- If you're talking about request times do you mean the time taken from receiving the request to delivering it to the client
- or just the time for generating the response?